# jqplot button hide/enable labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, jqplot

Does anybody know how to enable and hide the point Labels on an courve an JqPlot?

```
pointLabels: { show: false,
             hideZeros: true }
```

I found an example how to refresh the bar:

```
var storedData = [3, 7];

var plot1;
renderGraph();

$('button').click( function() 
    doUpdate();
);

function renderGraph() 
    if (plot1) 
        plot1.destroy();

    plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [storedData]);
}

function doUpdate() 
    var newVal = Math.random();
    storedData.push(newVal);
    renderGraph();
```

I've created an button, but can't access on the show variable?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the show variable using this path :

```
myplot.series[i].pointsLabels.show = true|false;
```

Where i is the index of the serie you want to modify.

**Edit** : You maybe need to apply myplot.replot() after this change but I'm not 100% sure.